# Does removing links for certain anchor text would affect my sites Google ranking?

Tags: backlinks, anchor

After Google penguin update i found some of my website's keyword lost ranking. I checked all the inbound backlinks of my website and all anchor texts. I noted two or three keywords has been getting backlink from a particular blogspot.

Now I plan to remove those backlinks, but if I do that i would lose more than 1000 backlinks. Does decreasing backlink would affect all my keyword's ranking in Google? or would it affect only those two or three keywords?
Overall backlink count according to GWT is 18,403 (it may varied on other SEO online tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many factors that are considered in order to give you a specific and completely accurate answer but if you have sitewide keyword rich anchor text backlink on an blogspot site then there is only really the most relevant instance of that backlink from that site that is passing any weight (link juice / PageRank) anyway.

From the minimal information, it is unlikely you would see much in the way of negative impact in organic rankings for said keyword that the anchor text contains but really you should analyse your existing backlinks for said search query / anchor text and identify exactly which backlinks are contributing to your site's rankings and work any strategy around this.